# Adapting non-standard properties in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gwt

I have an existing model compiled from java to javascript using GWT 2.7. Each property in this model has a getValue() and a setValue() method. The method names are not mangled.

I want to use these properties in {{}} expressions, specifically for binding using ngModel. I'm using the "getterSetter" option and a function in the $scope that wraps getValue()/setValue() in an angularJS getterSetter function.

The problem is that I don't want to duplicate this function in each scope. Is there any way of accessing a global function in an angularJS expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some searching and experimenting I found that I can use the `directive`'s `controller` to add the function to the `scope`.

```
.directive('wrapped', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.wrapper = function(prop) {
                // turns signal into getterSetter
                return function(newVal) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
                        prop.setValue(newVal);
                        }
                    return prop.getValue();
                    }
                }
            },
        scope : {
            model : '&'
            },
        templateUrl : 'template.html',
    }
})
```

A function in the scope can then be used in expressions in the template.

```
<p class="field {{model().status().isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}}">
    <span class="label">{{label}}:</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="wrap(model())" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" ></input>
</p>
```

I would love to hear from more experienced AngularJS programmers if there is a more idiomatic way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.

Can you just attach the function to the model prototype? That way you just can access it wherever you have an instance of the model.

Alternatively, you could create a wrapper class (basically a view-model) that has the interface you need, and delegates to the real model instance.

Comment: Attaching the function to the prototype works, but it is not what I'm looking for. There is a separate object for each observable property and many of them have unique classes, for example for calculated properties. I could add it to Object.prototype but that is quite brutal.

Comment: Adding a wrapper is exactly what I want to do in that function. If I were to wrap every property object ahead of time I would also have to recreate the structure.